# react-native debug js remotely

Tags: react-native

When the react-native is running, debug js remotely can be turned on and run normally. However, when the debug js remotely  is not turned on, the program will run incorrectly. Why

Answer (score 0):

Remote JS debugging makes the phone reliant to the browser Javascript engine that may be different in some cases (for me the problem came using `new Date()`.

When the remote JS debugging runs on device it uses the device JavascriptCore provided by the react-native application.

I'm not aware about other occasions where this may occur.